# Zend_Db does not correctly parse IN(:ids) parameter

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, oracle11g

I'm using Zend_Db with an Oracle adapter, and I'm trying to execute a query with an `IN()` statement in the `WHERE` clause.

The statement does not generate any errors, but also does not execute the update. I've tried the following forms:

```
$arrLinesCanceled = array('0000000001', '0000000002');

// attempt 1
$db->query(
    "UPDATE my_table SET STATUS = :status WHERE id IN(:lineIds)",
    array(
        'lineIds' => $arrLinesCanceled,
        'status' => 'C',
))->execute();

// attempt 2 (this actually errors out with 'not all parameters are bound')
$db->query(
    "UPDATE my_table SET STATUS = :status WHERE id IN(:lineIds)"
)->execute(array(
    'lineIds' => $arrLinesCanceled,
    'status' => 'C',
));

// attempt 3
$stmtUpdateDetailStatus = $db->prepare(
    "UPDATE my_table SET STATUS = :status WHERE id IN(:lineIds)");

$stmtUpdateDetailStatus->execute(array(
    'lineIds' => $arrLinesCanceled,
    'status' => 'C',
));

// last, very desperate attempt
$db->query("UPDATE my_table SET STATUS = :status WHERE id IN(:lineIds)", array(
    ':lineIds' => $arrLinesCanceled,
    ':status' => 'C',
))->execute(array(
    ':lineIds' => $arrLinesCanceled,
    ':status' => 'C',
));
```

to be sure the input in correct, here's an actual `print_r` of the `$arrLinesCanceled`

```
Array( [0] => 6617 [1] => 6618)
```

Is this not supported by Oracle 11 or the Zend_Db adapter? I can't see what could be wrong...

Comment: Are You sure the `$params` array indexes shouldn't contain a colon `:`, like `':lineIds' => $arrLinesCanceled,`???

Comment: I'm sure it works without them also, and it doesn't work with them either... I've updated the question with that attempt, which also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html#zend.db.statement.executing), when using **named** placeholders (those **`:placeholder`**) in Your SQL syntax, You then need to use the exact placeholder name also in the parameters array - that means, use a colon `:` as well:

```
$db->query(
    "UPDATE MOVE_LIST_EMPLOYEE_DETAILS SET STATUS = :status 
     WHERE MOVE_LIST_DETAIL_ID IN(:lineIds)"
)->execute(array(
    ':lineIds' => $arrLinesCanceled,
    ':status' => 'C',
));
```

Comment: We're using it without semicolon everywhere and that also seems to work. That beeing said, I've also tried it with semicolons, but still does not work.

Comment: And would You be so kind and provide us with `print_r($arrLinesCanceled)`? Maybe the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: I've added it to the question